# Is Brahma referring to the incidents of previous mahayugas?

Tags: mahabharata, yuga

Anusasana Parva contains a long discussion between Bhishma and Yudhishthira.

In the conversation, Yudhishthira once asks the following question

> "Yudhishthira said, 'Tell me, O learned sire that art versed in all the scriptures, of **Exertion and Destiny which is the most powerful**?'

Then Bhishma says that he will refer an *ancient* story of the conversation of Vasishtha and Brahma

> "Bhishma said, 'This **ancient story** of the conversation of Vasishtha and Brahma, O Yudhishthira, is an illustration in point. In olden times the adorable Vasishtha enquired of Brahma as to which among these two, viz., the Karma of a creature acquired in this life, or that acquired in previous lives (and called Destiny), is the more potent in shaping his life. Then, O king, the great god Brahma, who had sprung from the primeval lotus, answered him in these exquisite and well-reasoned words, full of meaning.'"

Observe that Bhishma told that he is saying an ancient conversation between Vasishtha and Brahma. The ancientness of the story is important here.

In that story Brahma says to Vasishtha that both exertion and destiny are important but exertion is mandatory from human.  In between, Brahma refers some people and incidents related to the people. You can see some of the lines below.

> "Brahma said, 'Nothing comes into existence without seed. Without seed, fruits do not grow. From seeds spring other seeds. Hence are fruits known to be generated from seeds. Good or bad as the seed is that the husbandman soweth in his field, good or bad are the fruits that he reaps. As, unsown with seed, the soil, though tilled, becomes fruitless, so, without individual Exertion, Destiny is of no avail...... **Aswatthaman and Rama, though both warriors and sons of Munis, failed to attain to heaven by reason of their own actions in this world.** Vasu, though he performed a hundred sacrifices like a second Vasava, was sent to the nethermost regions, for making a single false statement. Vali, the son of Virochana, righteously bound by his promise, was consigned to the regions under the Earth, by the prowess of Vishnu. .......**The Pandavas too regained their lost kingdom, of which they had been deprived by the powerful sons of Dhritarashtra, not through the intercession of the fates, but by recourse to their own valour** ............. **O best of Munis**, I have thus described all the merits of individual Exertion, after having always known them in their true significance with the aid of my yogic insight. By the influence of Destiny, and by putting forth individual Exertion, do men attain to heaven. The combined aid of Destiny and Exertion, becomes efficacious.'"
>
> [[Section 6, Anusasana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a006.htm)

How can Brahma say the incidents in the bold text above? Those incidents had happened just before (or) just after the aforementioned discussion between Bhishma and Yudhishthira. Did Brahma say the future to Vasishta?

Is Brahma referring to the incidents that had happened during previous mahayugas?  Or the Bhishma referring the recent conversation between Brahma and Vashishta as an ancient story (which is unlikely)?